# Can the same 3rd party app server cater to CCS and GCM both or should I create two versions of 3rd party app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

Can the same 3rd party app server cater to CCS and GCM both or should I create two versions of 3rd party app, one for GCM and one for CCS? and Why?

I am trying to understand if I can implement XMPP(TCP) and http endpoint connections for the same app server, or need individual ones for each.

please suggest which one is correct and/or better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is why would you need to implement both. If you only need cloud to device messaging, the GCM HTTP solution is much simpler to implement. If you need device to cloud messaging too, you must implement connection to GCM CCS, in which case you'll have both device to cloud and cloud to device messaging (and wouldn't need the HTTP solution).

That said, there shouldn't be any problem implementing both at the same server. For sending messages to the GCM HTTP endpoint you'll need to send HTTP requests to that endpoint. For sending and receiving messages to/from the GCM CCS endpoint, you'll have to establish a XMPP connection. Both can be done at the same server.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.Actually I am trying to implement push notification in http and xmpp both. So got some success with http using app engine endpoint bt with xmpp no progress..can you help me how can I implemente xmpp using eclipse.. I'll really appreciate your help...

Comment: @user3523641 Sorry, I only use the HTTP endpoint, so I can't help you.